# "To my right" vs. "on my right"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which one is correct and why?

> - *To* my right is Alex.
> - *On* my right is Alex.

What is the difference between *on* and *to* here?

Comment: Either preposition is fine. There isn't only one way to say it. There's no semantic difference between the two sentences. Both are grammatically correct and idiomatic American English.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, somewhere over the net I found someone trying to make out the difference between these two and I couldn't really comprehend that. But this helps :)

Comment: When I taught EFL in Japan, some of the college students in my classes told me that my English was incorrect because their high school teachers had told them that they could only one preposition in sentences like _I live **near** John_. Native Anglophones, however, say this in many ways, eg, _I live **next to** John_, _I live **close to** John_, _I live **nor far from** John_, _I live **by** John_, _I live **over by** John_, etc. English prepositions are usually flexible.

Comment: yeah totally agree with you.

Comment: Always format your sentences correctly on ELU. You would be interested in ELL ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am not sure about ELU. Would you mind telling me? I am a novice here :)

Comment: Oh I got it. Will do so from now on.

Answer (score 3):

user21497 is correct in that both prepositions are idiomatic and grammatically correct. However, to me, "Alex is on my right," or "On my right is Alex," imply that Alex is standing (or sitting, etc.) next to you, while "Alex is to my right," or "To my right is Alex," could more generally suggest that Alex is somewhere in the area to the right of you, without being adjacent to you. Again, though, both are correct and there is very little, if any, semantic difference.

Answer (score 0):

When it has to do with direction you'll have to use these-
I told Alex to come "To my right".

In some situations and context "To my right" sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it is the matter of standpoint. For example, if you are looking at three people in the following order: X Y Z: you would say "Y is in the middle. X is ON the left. Z is ON the right." Because you're looking at them from YOUR point of view. However, you would have to say X is TO the right of Y and Z is TO the left of X.